# How to remove lcoation icon from browser jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on jquery,Right now i am getting user location after click on "button" but if user select "block" option then page is redirecting but but but "block location icon" not removing until i refresh page manually, in other words i want whenever i click/select "block" option then page should redirect and "location icon should remove from browser as well",Here is my current code

```
 $(".in").click(function () {
            const options = {
                      enableHighAccuracy: true,
                      timeout: 5000,
                      maximumAge: 0
                    };

                    function success(pos) {
                      const crd = pos.coords;
                      var lats = crd.latitude;
                      var longs = crd.longitude;
                     $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "insert.php",
                            data: {
                                lats :lats,
                                longs :longs,
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                //further code
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    function error(err) {
                        var pathname = window.location.href;
                        alert('Please refresh page and select allow to continue for location');
                        window.location = pathname;
                     }
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
           });
```

Comment: Have you tried `location.reload()` instead?

Comment: @CBroe yes i tried but same result , actually location icon still there until i refresh page manually

Comment: Then what you want, might simply not be possible. Perhaps browser vendors saw a specific reason to only re-set this after an explicit hard reload triggered by the user themself.

Comment: Have you tried the usual cache-buster technique of appending a random GET parameter to the URL? Maybe that could convince the browser in this situation.

Comment: you can also try to force reload by `window.location.reload(true)` , if it will not work then try to use debugger, maybe this row just doesn't executed?